# What's the deal with testing RAM?

Tags: windows-7, memory, crash, bsod, memtest86+

Here's a little background:
Desktop computer came to my desk with 32GB (4x8) DDR3 1600MHz non-ECC, a GTX960 graphics card, and an OS (Windows 7 Pro) that wouldn't boot. After an overnight memory test, and several video memory tests, everything looked great! I repaired the OS offline and booted it up. Black screen and crash. I figured the videocard, which had just had a driver upgrade was faulty, so I popped it out and booted again. Everything looked great, and it ran like a dream. In order to fix the remaining problems, I upgrade to windows 10 per client request. Boots up great after the install. And then... Total annihilation. It rebooted and went straight to chkdsk where it recovered about 40GB of files. WinSxS was gone, the OS was beyond repair, and I was shocked. We tested the RAM for over 18 hours, running 5 passes with memtest, and a pass using another memory testing platform.

Here's the question:
How did all this testing take place without any indication of a problem, before this massive amount of data was nearly destroyed by bad memory? After replacing the memory the system runs fine. What happened, and what kinds of tests will actually catch a problem like this?

Comment: PCB fail because of an electrical fault

Comment: I think if that was the case then it probably should have failed in Memtest. Unless for some reason it would not.

Comment: You asked how it happened.  The memory failed electronically, why exactly they failed, is not possible for us to even hypothesis about

Comment: Actually, if you reread the post, I asked why testing didn't catch the problem, and how to test more effectively.

Comment: Why do you think that bad memory caused the data loss? All of the evidence you mention points elsewhere.

Comment: You say "by client request", "we", "to my desk" and so on. Am I correct in understanding that you provide computer repair services to others? (That is, this is not your personal system we are talking about, or that you are using as an example.)

Comment: We figured memory after reviewing the crashdump we finally got from the last crash. Replacing the memory entirely also resolved the problem, at least for now. It is not my personal system, and the "client" is a long-time friend.

Comment: If this had been a RAM problem, I would personally expect it to have manifested itself very, *very* differently. Even writing the file system structures to cover 40 GB of data on a common system takes a non-trivial amount of time, *especially* in modern CPU terms. The PC would have had ample time to outright crash during that time, and almost certainly would have.

Comment: *"We figured memory after reviewing the crashdump we finally got from the last crash."* I would recommend that you [edit] your question to include the specific information from the parsed dump that led you to draw this conclusion. As it stands, your question makes an unsubstantiated claim and then asks how that could happen. Note that comments should be regarded as ephemeral "post-it notes", and are subject to deletion at any time; however, question and answer posts remain, along with their revision history.

Comment: "*Replacing the memory entirely also resolved the problem*" Sure, but you also had to do a clean install of the OS, right? And that was something you hadn't done before. All of the evidence you've presented to us (I can't speak to evidence you haven't shared) suggests memory was not the problem.

Comment: The 40GB was chk'd out after about 3 total crashes, and consisted mainly of OS files, including files dumped in after two OS installs. So it's entirely possible that windows was reinstalled to locations that were not occupied by the corrupted data, and the total was recovered during a single chkdsk run.

Comment: Okay, so I guess you all don't trust me here. I took the old ram, popped it in a working machine (which I use for looking for testing hardware) and guess what? Second boot, hard crash, trashed OS. I'm really glad you guys are into proving that this is not a memory problem, but believe me, it's the memory. Both machines gave me the classic MEMORY_POOL_CORRUPTION, and the second machine now gives me CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED (as wininit fails to load a dll). So please, if we could move past the whole "It's not memory" thing I'd appreciate it. I want to know why testing missed the problem.

Comment: Perhaps if you included pertinent information like getting specific errors like "MEMORY_POOL_CORRUPTION" and "CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED" in your question, less guessing would ensue. ;)  So please, edit and update your question to add all this valuable information that currently only exists in your comments - plus anything further you think could help...

Comment: Maybe its a failing hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How did all this testing take place without any indication of a problem,

Easy, automated testing for a couple days cannot catch every defect that may arise.

> what kinds of tests will actually catch a problem like this?

There are none that are 100% accurate.  You do what you can, and have contingency plans in place.  IE: As a builder, offer a warranty and stock extra RAM.  As a user, ensure you keep a couple backups of the data you're putting onto a new, basically untested machine.

Related personal experience/anecdote:

"We tested the RAM for over 18 hours" -- When I worked as/for a system builder we used to burn-in the RAM (and system in general) in every system for 72 hours straight (minimum) before putting them out the door.  Many times we had RAM die on the 3rd day of burn-in, and plenty of times RAM still failed in the field after that.  Such is the nature of the beast.